# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file FontAwesome--fontawesometwo)

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I downloaded a tex file of a CV template from online edit to my local computer, but when I run the tex, there is a error:

`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file FontAwesome--fontawesometwo): Font FontAwesom
e--fontawesometwo at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

I cannot see the pdf. Following is the simplified sourcecode;

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\small{Undergraduate electrical and electronic engineer completing the final year of a master's degree. Passionate about science, with strong technical, business, and interpersonal skills for working in a team and successfully completing a project.}


% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

It's very strange that everything is ok if I use `LuaLatex`, but if I run a Chinese template, the pdf is following, it seems cannot show the Chinese.
[image]

Comment: If you have miktex: run tasks -> refresh font map files in the console (user mode).

Comment: Welcome! Off-topci: `\small` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How to do such thing in `Winedt`? And It's very strange that everything is ok if I use `LuaLatex`, but there is some problem of Chinese. Pls see my update.

Comment: I had the same problem. Then, I installed fontawesome5 and it works with Texmaker, but not with TeXworks.