# Compilation error with fontawesome and xelatex

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontawesome, miktex-update

I had the "good" idea to update my Miktex distro (not just the packages, but the whole distro, by uninstalling my old version and installing the last one (2021.3)). And... obviously, everything is broken, even after reinstalling all my former packages.

My problem is related to fontawesome and xelatex. If I try to compile the following source:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Test \faLightbulbO
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

> dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (3)

**Note:** it works with Lualatex, but I like to understand where the problem comes from. Moreover, compilation with xelatex *does* work when using fontawesome**5**, but some icons I used to use have been renamed (and for some reasons, I prefer to keep my existing source files as is...)

Comment: it works fine for me. Which probably means that you have two versions of the font around and dvipdfmx finds the wrong one. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1 ` to the begin of your document, and then compile on the command line with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" yourfilename`  and then check the exact pathes of the fonts used in the terminal output and in the log. Side remark: not everything broke. You have one rather small problem with one rather small package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just reinstalled all from scratch (and cleaned my Program and %appdata% folders). First, I had a new error with pdflatex (*Font FontAwesom e--fontawesometwo at 617 not found*), but [as you suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437690/pdftex-error-pdflatex-exe-file-fontawesome-fontawesometwo?noredirect=1&lq=1), rebuilding the font map files did the trick. Nevertheless, I still have the problem with xelatex; the suggested command line output gives the following file:  `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb`, which exists

Comment: More precisely, the output is: `fontmap: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome(Identity-H)`. The only file in `fontmap: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/` is `FontAwesome.pfb`.

Comment: it is wrong that it uses the pfb, it should use the otf with xelatex. On my miktex is uses `MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf`. Do you have this font?

Comment: Yes I have. Putting it in `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/` solves the compilation error... but the characters are not shown in the PDF...

Comment: no, you shouldn't move the font. You need to tell xelatex not to use the pfb. Try `\renewfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.otf}` after loading the package.

Comment: Unfortunately, same issue :( It's all the stranger since it's a fresh install...
Note: maybe we should move this discussion to chat?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer some news: the error with dvipdfmx appears only **after** updating Miktex (on a Miktex 21.3 fresh install, there is no compilation error with xelatex, but fontawesome characters are absent un the PDF; *after* update, I have the error described above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123306/discussion-between-ulrike-fischer-and-greg82).

Comment: Hey, @Greg82 - I am curious how you narrowed the problem to fontawesome here. Which logs helped you?

Comment: @pratnala - As described in the error message `dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font`, it was a font error. I tried with a minimal example, until I found that the error was caused by fontawesome. All credit for solving the problem goes to Ulrike Fischer

Comment: I see, so you just tried with various packages to narrow it down? Thanks for the great discussion to you and @Ulrike Fischer. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force xelatex to use the file name with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\renewfontfamily{\FA}{fontawesome}[Extension=.otf]
\begin{document}
Test \faLightbulbO
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I just wonder why I have to specify the extension, while it worked well before... :/